# Getting a TypeError: use_force_update_1.default is not a function error when using use-react-router library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Does anybody know what this error means? The error is occuring at the point where I call the `useReactRouter()` hook from use-react-router.

```
use_force_update_1.default is not a function
TypeError: use_force_update_1.default is not a function
    at Object.useRouter [as default] (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:95808:47)
    at Home(http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:40188:33)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:75154:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:78440:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:79736:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:64746:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:64790:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:64847:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:84721:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:83968:16)
```

It works fine when I do it in codesandbox, but for some reason, I am getting this error in my actual app.

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "use-react-router": "^1.0.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(<App />);
```

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Home from "./components/Home";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Home />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Home.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import useReactRouter from "use-react-router";

const Home = () => {
  const { history, location, match } = useReactRouter();
  return <div>My location is {location.pathname}!</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: What benefit do you gain from using this `use-react-router` library I've never heard of over just using the React hooks `react-router-dom` exports, e.g. `useHistory`, `useLocation`, and `useParams`? Also, with React18 you'll want to bump to ***at least*** `react-router-dom@5.3.3` to address some possible compatibility issues.

Comment: Looks like there's possibly an issue in some `ModalForm` component. Can you [edit] to include all relevant code you are working with as part of a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: I have edited it. Basically, that error shows up any time I call the useReactRouter() hook